# What is this material under the carpet pad in my 50's home?

Tags: underlayment

I pulled up some carpet in my house, built in 1954, in Des Moines, Iowa. Under the carpet pad is a rubbery black layer with marks on it that resemble Treadbright, used for truck bed accessories. Is it dangerous?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Dangerous? Only if you're allergic to horses.

The premium carpet padding of the day was horsehair in a matrix of rubber. It was much more durable than foam rubber waffle-type padding. It retained its springiness and loft while plain rubber would just disintegrate after a few years.

Answer (score 0):

Before the advent of foam, the underlay was rubber.

When we built our first house - 1981, we had rubber underlay.

In 1995 with our second house, rubber underlay was premium and foam was the cheap option.

Both times, the underlay was held together with jute or sacking. It was more spongy than foam.  It was not horsehair in New Zealand at that time.  Perhaps, it was used earlier than that.